# LuaTeX node question: Can hpack be somehow reapplied for display math to adjust to new width?

Tags: math-mode, luatex, tex-core

***This is a LuaTeX node library question intended to understand what all it can do, am not looking for a usual LaTeX answer.***

Let's say I have a set of display equations in an `align*` environment that is set in a `\vbox`. `align*` environment nicely centers the contents to the natural width of the `\vbox`. Then I copy the nodelist produced by `align*` environment from the `\vbox`, and try to **recursively redo hpack** with the intention to center it again on a page with different text width. But this recipe doesn't work to center the equation, moreover it messes up the math spacing produced by TeX. Can something be done about it? The constrain is that you have to work on the nodelist produced by `align*` (no converting `align*` environment again to nodelist), and it should naturally adapt to the width of the page.

> A sidenote question from my code below: Performing `node.write(tex.getbox(0).head)` twice makes the program hang. Why is that so?

Output:
[image: Screenshot of output]

Code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\directlua{
    nodetree = require"nodetree"
    local hlist_id = node.id("hlist")
    function rehpack(n,h)
        for nn in node.traverse_id(hlist_id,h) do
            rehpack(nn,nn.head)
        end
        if not (n == nil) and n.id == hlist_id and not (n.head == nil) then
            texio.write_nl("Previous width = " .. n.width)
            local newn = node.hpack(h)
            n.width = newn.width
            newn.head = nil
            node.free(newn)
            texio.write_nl(".....New width = " .. n.width)
        end
    end
}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[1]

\setbox0=\vbox{{\begin{align*}
x^2+y^2 &= z^2\\
a^2+b^2+1 &= c^3
\end{align*}}}\copy0

\blindtext[1]

\newgeometry{textwidth=3in}

\blindtext[1]

\directlua{
    local box0 = tex.getbox(0).head
    box0.width = tex.sp("3in")
    % nodetree.print(tex.getbox(0).head) % to print contents of box0 
    rehpack(nil,tex.getbox(0).head)
    % nodetree.print(tex.getbox(0).head) % to print contents of box0
    node.write(tex.getbox(0).head)
}

\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

Console:

```
Previous width = 14208860
.....New width = 983040
Previous width = 0
.....New width = 0
Previous width = 297726
.....New width = 261030
Previous width = 297726
.....New width = 261030
Previous width = 2110904
.....New width = 2037512
Previous width = 2110904
.....New width = 2037512
Previous width = 3162361
.....New width = 2037512
Previous width = 297726
.....New width = 261030
Previous width = 1496049
.....New width = 1459353
Previous width = 1496049
.....New width = 1459353
Previous width = 1496049
.....New width = 1459353
Previous width = -11761186
.....New width = -11761186
Previous width = 16419596
.....New width = 15258051
Previous width = 0
.....New width = 0
Previous width = 297726
.....New width = 261030
Previous width = 297726
.....New width = 261030
Previous width = 3162361
.....New width = 3088969
Previous width = 3162361
.....New width = 3088969
Previous width = 3162361
.....New width = 3088969
Previous width = 297726
.....New width = 261030
Previous width = 1471801
.....New width = 1435105
Previous width = 1471801
.....New width = 1435105
Previous width = 1496049
.....New width = 1435105
Previous width = -11761186
.....New width = -11761186
Previous width = 16419596
.....New width = 16285260
```

Comment: `tex.write(tex.getbox(0).head)` ? tex.write accepts a string (or table of strjngs) with tex sytax that is written back to the input buffer This doesn't seem to error but I'm not sure what it is doing.

Comment: Oh... good catch, it should have been `node.write`. Weird, it writes nodelist to pdf instead of erroring out. Also, I still get that error I mention in sidenote with if I do `node.write(tex.getbox(0).head)` twice.

Comment: What you want is the Lua equivalent of `\hbox{\hss\box\oldvbox\hss}`.

Comment: @HenriMenke yes except that would stop the align breaking (not relevant here admittedly as it is copied via `\copy` not `\unvcopy` but stepping through it and changing the centering skips would allow that.

Comment: @reportaman If you use `tex.write(tex.getbox(0).head)` then the literal node you specified is inserted into the list, not a copy. So if you insert the same node twice, the second one will be the `next` entry of the first. But since they are the same node, this means that the node will be it's own `next`, leading to an infinite loop.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Thanks that clarifies the reason for infinite loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think hpack is what you want, you need to reset the left (at least) skips to re-center, something like this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\directlua{
    nodetree = require"nodetree"
    local hlist_id = node.id("hlist")
    function rehpack(h,oldw,neww)
    local hlist_id = node.id("hlist")
        for nn in node.traverse_id(hlist_id,h) do
     local lsk=nn.head
     if lsk.id == 12 then
     local tsk=node.getglue(nn.head,false)
      node.setglue(nn.head,tsk - (tex.sp(oldw)-tex.sp(neww))/2)
     end
        end
    end
}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[1]

\setbox0=\vbox{{\begin{align*}
x^2+y^2 &= z^2\\
a^2+b^2+1 &= c^3
\end{align*}}}\copy0


\blindtext[1]
\newdimen\oldtw
\oldtw=\textwidth
\newgeometry{textwidth=3in}

\blindtext[1]

\directlua{
    local box0 = tex.getbox(0).head
    box0.width = tex.sp("3in")
    rehpack(tex.getbox(0).head,"\the\oldtw","3in")
    % nodetree.print(tex.getbox(0).head) % to print contents of box0
    node.write(tex.getbox(0))
}

\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats a great idea!